# How to store multiple string inputs and displaying it after

Tags: c++

I'm just starting in studying C++, and I am doing a simple challenge which is GWA Calculator, but I am having a problem finding out how to store the multiple strings input (which is the Subjects/Course) and displaying it after together with the Units and Grades. I am really sorry, but I tried finding out how and I couldn't find an answer. Hope you can help me out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void calculateGWA();

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int input;
    cout << "\t\t -------------------------------------------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|                                GWA Calculator                           |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t -------------------------------------------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|            MENU:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   " <<                                         "|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|                   1. Calculate GWA (General Weighted Average)\t\t   " <<      "|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|                   2. Calculate CGWA (Cummulative Weighted Average)       " << "|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|                   4. Exit Application\t\t\t\t\t   " <<                        "|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|                                                                         |"  << endl;
    cout << "\t\t -------------------------------------------------------------------------- " << endl;
    sub:
    cout << "\t\tEnter your choice: ";
    cin >> input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
                calculateGWA();
                break;
        case 2:
                //calculateCGPA();
                break;
        case 3:
                main();
                break;
        case 4:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
        default:
            cout << "You have entered wrong input.Try again!\n" << endl;
            goto sub;
            break;
    }
    
}

void calculateGWA()
{
    int q;
    system("cls");
    cout << "-------------- GWA Calculator -----------------"<<endl;
    cout << " How many course(s)?: ";
    cin >> q;

    char c_name[50];
    float unit [q];
    float grade [q];

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Course Name " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> c_name;
        cout << "Enter the Unit " << c_name << ": ";
        cin >> unit[i];
        cout << "Enter the Grade " << c_name << ": ";
        cin >> grade[i];
        cout << "-----------------------------------\n\n" << endl;
    }

    float sum = 0;
    float tot;
    for(int j = 0; j < q; j++)
    {
        tot = unit[j] * grade[j];
        sum = sum + tot;
    }

    float totCr = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < q; k++)
    {
        totCr = totCr + unit[k];
    }
    system("cls");

    // PRINTS OUT THE COURSES - UNITS - GRADES AND GWA //
    cout << "\t\t =============================================================== " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|           COURSE             |      UNIT      |     GRADE     |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t =============================================================== " << endl;
    cout << "Total Points: " << sum << " \n Total Credits: " << totCr << " \nTotal GPA: " << sum/totCr << " ." << endl;
    
    cout << c_name << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "===================================" << endl;

    sub:
    int inmenu;
    cout << "\n\n\n1. Calculate Again" << endl;
    cout << "2. Go Back to Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit This App \n\n" << endl;
    cout << "Your Input: " << endl;
    cin >> inmenu;

    switch(inmenu)
    {
        case 1:
                calculateGPA();
                break;
        case 2:
                main();
                break;
        case 3:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default:
              cout << "\n\nYou have Entered Wrong Input!Please Choose Again!" << endl;
              goto sub;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char c_name[50];` is an array of 50 characters. You want a `std::vector<std::string` instead

Comment: What do your course material, tutorial or books say about the standard containers, like `std::vector`? And what do they say about `std::string`?

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. But here's how to make some progress. Put this code aside, instead just write a simple program to solve the issue of how to store multiple strings. This will let you concentrate on that problem alone. Then when you've solved that problem come back to this program and apply the knowledge you've gained.

Comment: You can apply the same technique to other problems with this program. For instance, how to repeatedly show a menu without duplicating all your menu code.

Comment: I would suggest you try to split you program into smaller components, and to focus on one issue at a time. Like one function to input the data, another one to display it, and one to do the computation, ... also, have a look at vector and string tutorial / book. Another good practice would be to get rid of the 'jump' and 'goto' (for example using a 'while')

Comment: @eck.98 In C++ you may not call the function main() recursively.

Comment: And don't use labels and `goto` instead of loops.

Comment: `char c_name[50];` are you forced to use c-strings? Modern `c++` would use `std::vector<std::string>` for a dynamic array of strings to store multiple strings.